# parallel programming for tomcat web application

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, servlets, parallel-processing

I am writing a web application to be deployed on **tomcat**. I am writing a servlet. When I receive a request, I need to call 10 other different websites. Then aggregate responses received from all of them and respond. Now if i call every website in a sequence, it takes lot of time. Is there a way to complete this task in **parallel**?
I mean is there a way to call 10 websites in parallel? Can I use java multi-threading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use threading, but it would probably be alot easier if you used e.g., [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) with a connection pool of `10`.

See [2.8.4 Pooling connection manager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e638) for further configuration details.

Comment: Rather use `HttpClient` version 4 (and higher) instead.

Comment: i am looking into it. Will let you know if i succeed. Thanks guys

Comment: I tried it, it works. I think this is the right way. Thank you Johan.

Comment: i am using ThreadSafeClientConnManager for multithreading in java application. My ThreadSafeClientConnManager object is static, so it remains until application is running. What will happen if i am never calling closeExpiredConnections() or closeIdleConnections(). Will it crash my application in long run?

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use a Java EE 6 compliant application server such as GlassFish.

EJB 3.1 introduced asynchronous method calls:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaEE/JavaEE6Overview_Part3.html#asynejb

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html

Comment: Just to add - you can also have asychronous servlets in Java EE 6 - http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html#asyncSupported%28%29